# Where can I get the object identifiers for signature algorithms

Tags: java, signing, asn.1

I got the object identifier for dsaWithSha1 as (1 2 840 10040 4 3) from the rfc2875. I would like to know, is there any help page to get the object ids of below signing algorithms.

```
NONEwithRSA
MD2withRSA
MD5withRSA
SHA1withRSA SHA256withRSA
SHA384withRSA
SHA512withRSA
NONEwithDSA
SHA1withDSA
NONEwithECDSA
SHA1withECDSA
SHA256withECDSA
SHA384withECDSA
SHA512withECDSA
(ECDSA)
```

How can I send the signed information in ASN.1 format. Is there any java library available to send the signed information in ASN.1 format and extract the information from ASN.1 structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can search the OIDs here http://www.oid-info.com/basic-search.htm.

There are various libraries for encoding to ASN.1:

- https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html which offers the cryptography APIs that you need along with an ASN.1 serializer
- http://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-java/asn1-java.html
- https://www.obj-sys.com/